# Write Test On Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, testing, phpunit

Hello I want to write test for my Api and I create file called:

LessonsTest.php

```
use App\Lesson;
use Tests\ApiTester;

/**
* Class LessonsTest
*  That Test Our Lessons
*/
class LessonsTest extends ApiTester
{
    /**
    * @test
    *  Test All Lessons pass
    */
    public function it_fetches_lessons()
    {
        //        Make Lesson
        $this->times(5)->makeLesson();
        //      Get URL we want to test
        $this->getJson('api/v1/lessons');
        //        Pass Ok Response
        $this->assertResponseOk();
    }

    /**
    * Make Lesson method
    * @param array $lessonFields
    */
    private function makeLesson($lessonFields = [])
    {
        $lesson = array_merge([
            'title' => $this->fake->sentence,
            'body' => $this->fake->paragraph,
            'some_bool' => $this->fake->boolean
        ], $lessonFields);

        while ($this->times--) Lesson::create($lesson);
    }
}
```

Now as you see its extend from ApiTester file:

```
namespace Tests;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class ApiTester extends TestCase
{
    protected $fake;
    protected $times = 1;

    /**
    * ApiTester constructor.
    * @param $faker
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fake = Faker::create();
    }

    protected function times($count)
    {
        $this->times = $count;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

so its all write now problem I have when I try to test:

**vendor\bin\phpunit tests\LessonsTest.php**

I get this error:

> 1) LessonsTest::it_fetches_lessons
>   ErrorException: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

I research a lot but I could not find solution

Comment: `Log::info($this->fake->sentence);` what do you get?

Comment: Hello Thank you For your Response where should i test this code?

Comment: Inside of `makeLesson` above the `array_merge`

Comment: i pass  `private function makeLesson($lessonFields = [])
    {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info($this->fake->sentence);`
this code as you say but when i try to run the phpunit in cmd again i get same error